# Undefined symbol between two dependance libraries

Tags: linker, dependencies, static-libraries, symbols, nm

First of all sorry for the title, but I don't really know how to put it. Is you have any better idea feel free to edit it.

Secound, I did extensive research but couldn't find a solution. Don't be mad if you find the solution on google. I looked for it and i didn't find it (or i'm stupid, which is also possible)

---

For my problem :

I'm trying to compile a program `hacc` which amoung his numerous dependencies has `diy` and `tess`. Furthermore, `diy` is also one of the dependencies of `tess`.

I got `diy` compiled to `libdiy.a`

I got `tess` compiled to `libtess.a`

When I try to compile `hacc` I've got an error saying

```
[...]/tess/install/lib/libtess.a(tess.cpp.o): in function « item_type(ompi_datatype_t**) »:
tess.cpp:(.text+0x13e): undefined reference to « DIY_FLOAT »
```

nm tells me :

```
nm [...]/diy/install/lib/libdiy.a | grep DIY_FLOAT
0000000000000010 D DIY_FLOAT

nm [...]/tess/install/lib/libtess.a | grep DIY_FLOAT
U DIY_FLOAT
U DIY_FLOAT
```

`hacc` is compiled with the linking flags

```
-L${LIBS}/diy/install/lib  -ldiy  \
-L${LIBS}/tess/install/lib -ltess \
```

Where did I do something wrong ? Should I try to compile `tess` by including all symbol from the dependencies inside `libtess.a` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Furthermore, diy is also one of the dependencies of tess.

That means that `-ldiy` *must* follow `-ltess` on the command line, i.e. your order of libraries on the link line is incorrect. More detailed explanation [here](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) and [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking).

Comment: That for the link, I didn't actually believed that the order of lib flags had such an importance ...